# Clifford+T synthesis with imperfect T gates

Tags: gate-synthesis, magic-states

From [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6964v2), it has been nicely shown that the number of perfect $T$ gates required to simulate arbitrary single-qubit gates grows ***linearly*** with $\log(1/\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ is the error tolerance between the target gate and the simulated gate. Particularly, the linear dependence for any $R_Z(\theta)$ is $N\approx3.067\log_2(1/\epsilon)-4.322$.

What if the $T$ gates available is no longer perfect? Say the available $T'$ gates have fidelity $(1-\epsilon_g)$ from the perfect gate, how does the gate infidelity affect the performance of gate synthesis?

**EDIT**: Any related reference about how the T gate error is accumulated during the synthesis is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If your T gates aren't perfect, then you will need to do state distillation to make them good enough that the error you accumulate from using $N$ of them is less than the error you incur from approximating the target rotation with Clifford+T. So your question really comes down to how expensive is state distillation.

If you don't distill, then you simply hit a lower bound on the precision you can achieve because as the rotation-approximation error goes down from increasing the sequence length the bad-T error will increase. At some point the bad-T error will exceed the rotation-approximation error, setting your no-distillation precision floor.

Comment: Do you have any references that cover how bad-T errors accumulate during the gate synthesis?

Comment: @Yunzhe I don't.